# Disable "Replace 'Property' with methods" quick action in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, code-analysis

When the cursor is on an auto-property line like

```
public int Id { get; set; }
```

then Visual Studio 2017 displays the Quick Action lightbulb with the following suggestion:

> Replace 'Id' with methods

I'm always attracted by these lightbulbs, they are often helpful... but this one is really annoying. How could I disable it?
I'm already using a custom ruleset file for Code Analysis but cannot find a rule for this one.

Comment: The following question discuss the purpose of this quick action but does not mention how to disable it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45610419

Comment: Please don't take that as an insult, I just find this phrasing somewhat amusing: "I'm always attracted by these lightbulbs"... Are you a moth? Not everything that's bright and shiny should also be implemented in code...

Comment: I strongly recommend that you get used to them - they are there to help you.

Comment: @ZoharPeled ^^ I did not realized that when I wrote this :D The reason I'm "attracted" is because I just switched to VS2017 and .NET4.7, and the IDE started to show me lots of suggestions that were not there in VS2015... Most of them are helpful (collection initializers, etc.) @ DavidG I guess I'll have to.

Comment: As I wrote, not everything should be implemented. I like to write code like `this.PropertyName = value`. VS always suggest to remove the `this.`. I never do. I think it makes the code more readable, and in the end of the day, this is just a matter of opinion. Of course there are cases when the suggestions VS makes are worth accepting.

Comment: Fortunately for you, that suggestion can be disabled. The one I'm mentionning cannot (at least, I cannot find how). Hence the question.

Comment: Well, I never bothered to check. I simply ignore it and move on :-)